# Centered div containing a fixed fix

Tags: html, css, centering, fixed

Can a centered div contain a fixed div?

I would like to center a fixed nav box and a scrolling main box side-by-side together in any big window. I can fix the nav box in a non-centered view (first code below), or center the view with a scrolling nav box (second code), but have been unable to combine these two traits, after many tries including multiple nested wrappers. Maybe fixed and centering are incompatible? If this is possible I will appreciate seeing how it is done. Thank you.

(1) Fixed nav box, scrolling main box, not centered:

```
<style>
#nav {position:fixed; top:50px; left:80px; width:270px; height:400px; background:#ddd }
#main {position:absolute; top:50px; left:380px; width:800px; height:1200px; background:#eee}
</style>

<div id="nav">
</div>
<div id="main">
</div>
</div>
```

(2) Centered, nav box scrolls (#bigscreen here is just a temp to show the centering):

```
<style>
#bigscreen {width:2000px; height:1200px;}
#window {width:100%; height:100%; display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center;}
#wrap {position:relative; width:1125px;height:800px; background:bisque}
#nav {position:absolute; top:54px; left:20px; width:270px; height:400px; background:#ddd }
#main {position:absolute; top:54px; left:300px; width:800px; height:640px; background:#eee}
</style>

<div id="bigscreen">
    <div id="window">
        <div id="wrap">
            <div id="nav">
            </div>
            <div id="main">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to create a wrapper(`#content-wrapper` in my answer) that includes `#nav` and `#main` divs. Then add `display: flex` for that wrapper to set child divs horizontally. To align the wrapper into the center, define a fixed `width`(1100px in my answer) and set left, right `margin` to `auto`.

Then add `position: relative` to the wrapper. That allows you to play with css `position` property in child divs within the wrapper.

Finally, add `position: fixed` for `#nav` div to set fixed position and add `position: absolute` & `left: 300px`(in my answer) for `#main` div to scroll in the wrapper.

See below.

```html
<style>
  #content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 1100px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    display: flex;
  }
  
  #nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 270px;
    height: 400px;
    background: #ddd
  }
  
  #main {
    position: absolute;
    left: 300px;
    width: 800px;
    height: 1200px;
    background: #eee
  }
</style>

<div id="content-wrapper">
  <div id="nav"></div>
  <div id="main"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect. This code is a solid core for any mix of diversely positioned divs. Two divs, side by side, centered together between side margins adjusting to any viewport; small div stays in place, large div scrolls. This configuration of position values is notable: the parent’s relative position makes it the anchor reference for both the fixed-position child and the absolute-position child, replacing the viewport's default reference.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

#nav {
  margin-right: 10px;
  width:20%;
  background: rgb(240,240,240);
}

#main {
  width: 80%;
  background: rgb(240,240,240);
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#content {
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2000px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay">
    <div id="nav">
    </div>
    <div id="main">
      <div id="content">Overflow content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If this is the result you're looking for you should focus only on the following lines, they are the most important ones to achieve this.

```
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

#nav {
  width:20%;
}

#main {
  width: 80%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Edit: You can click on **full page** to see the result in expanded height.

Comment: This works well, though does not center the paired divs within variable side margins.